# How can I turn on a pager for the output of git status?

Tags: git

I want the output of `git status` to be returned in a `less`-like environment. This already works for `git diff`, but not `git status`. I already tried adding the following to `~/.gitconfig`, but it didn't work:

```
[core]
  pager = less
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to do it, but, is `git status | less` too difficult? You only really need it when you have a lot of modified files.

Comment: @WesFreeman it is a bit annoying than this. Git will not preserve colors when piped to less and there is no `--color=always` to `git status`. If there were such an option, the one would have to type `git status --color=always | less -R` - not so succinct, right?

Comment: This is also super useful now that we have `git status -vv`, which adds on `git-diff`'s output to the end.

Comment: @EveFreeman "You only really need it when you have a lot of files" which is all the time in the project on which I'm working. Build artifacts number in the hundreds on this project, and the .gitignore is large, but doesn't cover them all.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can turn on and off paging of specific commands with the [`pager.<cmd>`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) setting, in this case `pager.status`:

> If the value is boolean, turns on or off pagination of the output of a particular Git subcommand when writing to a tty. Otherwise, turns on pagination for the subcommand using the pager specified by the value of pager.<cmd>.

Run the following to enable paging for `status` subcommand:

```
git config --global pager.status true
```

or manually add the following to the end of your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[pager]
    status = true
```

If you just want to turn paging on or off for a specific invocation, you can use option `-p`/`--paginate` respectively `-P`/`--no-pager` to the `git` command itself as well, e.g.:

```
git -p status
```

Comment: And this seems to preserve the colorization as well!  Many thanks!

Comment: For the aim that one answer should answers all aspects, it would be nice to include the hint to `--paginate`/`--no-pager` here as well.

Comment: Oh, I just overlooked it because it was "buried" within the documentation quote. My bad.

Answer (score 12):

For one-off:

```
git -p status
```

Or `--paginate`. Colourised. Works everywhere. Including errors/help.

`git -p status -h` is much better than having to grab stderr with `git status -h |& less`

Though long help messed up my terminal: `git -p status --help`

Comment: If you want to run a command without a pager, there's also `git -P` equivalent to `git --no-pager`