# make git branch show branches inline (version 2.17.1)

Tags: git

Before git version **2.17.1** (no more than 4 versions back), when you ran

```
git branch
```

you would get an inline list of branches and your terminal was ready for a new command.

In version **2.17.1** you get a list of branches as a new screen, and have to press `q` to quit it. After you quit, you no longer see your branches.

Without downgrading, how can I list branches inline as before?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8883248/3906760

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git-branch command behaves like less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341920/git-branch-command-behaves-like-less)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The [config setting `pager.<cmd>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pagerltcmdgt) works for me:

```sh
git config --global pager.branch 'false'
```

Before running that command, `git branch` used a pager. After that command, `git branch` printed the list of branches directly to the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for finding this, I was worried I'd have to start typing `git branch | cat` from now on but a quick search led me to this simple answer!

Answer (score 8):

You can force the desired behavior with the `--no-pager` flag

```
git --no-pager branch
```

or edit `.gitconfig` to include this

```
[pager]
    branch = false
```

which will disable the new behavior

Comment: Explain what you're doing Boris